# Kotlin - Find minimum value in an IntArray within range of indices

Tags: loops, kotlin, iterator, idioms

I am refactoring some older Java code over to Kotlin. There is a function that returns the index of the minimum value held by an element in a Kotlin `IntArray` within the range [`a`, `b`]. The range values default to 0 and the size of the array - 1.

I would like to do something along the lines of...

```
return data.minOf().indexOf()
```

...but while only iterating between the `a` and `b` indices of `data`.

Here is the function:

```
// data is the IntArray property that I'm looping through. 
fun absMinIndex(a: Int = 0, b: Int = (data.size - 1)) : Int {
    var minVal = data[a]
    var minIndex = 0

    for (i in (a + 1)..b) {
        val e = data[i]
        if (e < minVal) {
            minVal = e
            minIndex = i
        }
    }
    return maxIndex
}
```

This [for loop] solves the issue nicely by never visiting indices out of range, and by not generating a copied array/sub-array. I'm wondering if it could be done 'prettier'.

**Question**

Is there a more idiomatic Kotlin approach to iterating through an array within a range that would not negatively impact the performance of my current solution?

Edited some code for clarity.

Comment: I don't think you can make it prettier without introducing boxing of the Ints, which would impact performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tenfour04 suggested, not much you can do without loosing performance. But as per your idea with changing the way you call it, you can make it an extension function.

```
fun IntArray.findIndexOfMinInRange(a: Int = 0, b: Int = this.size - 1): Int {
    var maxVal = get(a)
    var maxIndex = 0

    for (i in (a + 1)..b) {
        if (get(i) < maxVal) {
            maxVal = get(i)
            maxIndex = i
        }
    }
    return maxIndex
}

//and call it like this: 

data.findIndexOfMinInRange(0, 15) //or without anything in the parentheses for the default values
```

One thing that I would change is the variable names inside the function, we are searching for the minimum value, not max, and also for the index of the minimum, not the maximum index. Also maybe (big maybe) creating a val of `data[it]` instead of accessing it twice might be better (honestly not sure, we would be trading a `.get` for a few bytes of memory).

So all in all, I'd probably leave it at this:

```
fun IntArray.findIndexOfMinInRange(fromIndex: Int = 0, toIndex: Int = this.size - 1): Int {
    var min = get(fromIndex)
    var indexOfMin = fromIndex

    for(i in (fromIndex + 1)..toIndex){
        val current = get(i)
        if (current < min) {
            min = current
            indexOfMin = i
        }
    }

    return indexOfMin
}

//would be called in the same way the one above
```

Also, a note of caution, if you create an `IntArray` of a certain size, and do not populate it in full, the default values it will hold for the non populated ones is `0`. If you do:

```
val data = IntArray(6)
data[0] = 10
data[1] = 11
data[2] = 100
data[3] = 9
data[4] = 50
```

Then the actual array is `[10, 11, 100, 9, 50, 0]`.

Comment: I think `for (i in...` is preferable to `range.forEach`. Aside from being more readable, the compiler optimizes out the IntRange so it doesn't have to be instantiated. It's a single allocation for a tiny class, though, so pretty minor. Something to keep in mind for iterating 2D collections, though.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I wasn't planning on posting the `.forEach` part, but did try to see how it looks, and forgot to change it back.

Comment: Alex T, thank you for noticing the variable names. As you might have guessed, there is a similarly structured function that returns the max, and I must have mixed them up when I copied stuff over. I'll make the edits to clear that up. I am going to mark this as the correct answer, as it answers my questions, and frankly I think using extension functions is precisely what I need to do to refactor/downsize some of this code.

Comment: Thank you to the users who suggested extension functions!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this approach would be more idiomatic:

1. Use `IntRange` as an input parameter
2. Define extension method for `IntArray` providing custom iterator to traverse the list in the desired range wrapping values into `IndexedValue`:

```kotlin
fun IntArray.withIndexInRange(range: IntRange = 0..lastIndex) = Iterable {
    require(range.first >= 0 && range.last <= lastIndex)
    object : Iterator<IndexedValue<Int>> {
        private var index = range.first
        override fun hasNext() = index <= range.last
        override fun next() = IndexedValue(index, this@withIndexInRange[index++])
    }
}
```

3. Use `minByOrNull` method from stdlib to find minimal value or wrap it into another extension method for convenience:

```kotlin
fun <T : Comparable<T>> Iterable<IndexedValue<T>>.indexOfMinOrNull() = minByOrNull { it.value }?.index
```

Usage:

```
data.withIndexInRange(a..b).indexOfMinOrNull()
```

Note, that this will have some performance penalties (creation and GC of N extra objects), but as [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) says:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil

So, I believe better readability worth it.

Comment: Worth noting you don't need the custom iterator -- you could do something like `intArray.sliceArray(a..b).withIndex().minByOrNull { it.value }!!.index + a`

Comment: Yes, but this is not that readable and would allocate a new array